# How to represent those types of values in a tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a dataset like this:

```
(0, 1), UpDownUpUp            
(2, 3), UpUpUpDownDownDown   
(0, 2), DownUp               
(0, Undefined), DownUp
```

How to represent this type of data in a PyTorch tensor? So I can then train a neural network with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

- You keep the values as they are, replacing the undefined with 9 (we will use 9 to represent [do nothing])
- You encode the labels into integers 5, 6
- Convert your variables into lists
- For every batch, take the length of the longest sequence
- Pad the input and the labels with 9s to match the length you found at previous step

Resulting dataset will look like the following input and target pairs:

```
[0, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9], [5, 6, 5, 5, 9, 9]
[2 ,3, 9, 9, 9, 9], [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
[0, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9], [6, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [6, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but isn't the neural network accepting only a tensor of always the same size ? Also, should I "merge" those values together (ex for 1st row: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]) when feeding it to the NN?

Comment: Aha Yep you are right for the cases that the batch size > 1. See my updated answer.

Comment: I still wonder how you'd feed two lists to the NN. In your example I see two lists separated by a comma in each row.

Comment: Each of these "lines" are an input-target pair. x and y. I will mark that in answer

Comment: Sorry, there's a misunderstanding. The dataset values shown in the original post are not inputs and targets, they are only inputs. I haven't added the targets because they're easy to represent for me (one-hot encoding).

Comment: Oh I see. What are they then? Can you describe the tuple and the UpDown sequences to let me understand what they represent?

Comment: Sure, the tuple represents the value of the initial random event assigned to the player. It's a playing card. So a tuple (0, Undefined) means the player received the card "0" but hasn't reached the state of the game where he received the second card (hence the Undefined). The UpDown sequence represent the actions made by the player **and** his opponent and describes the current state of the game.

Comment: I see. Then what is the training task here? I thought you want your network to predict the actions

Comment: I want the network to predict the next **optimal** action given thousands of previous examples. my dataset looks like this: (0, 1) UpDown ---> Down.

Comment: Ow then this is like a time series prediction problem. Maybe not exactly. Still, I would go for the following: I would encode all the possible cards and the moves in the game with unique characters and concatenate the resulting two arrays to create a single time serie. Then I would probably take the last action of each line and use it as the ground truth. But I am no expert on this kind of task. I will update the answer

Comment: do you know if there's a way to convert a tensor like [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1] to a single float?

Comment: for a tensor t, first convert to a string `st= ''.join(np.array(np.array(t.data.numpy(), dtype=int), dtype=str))` and then I assume that your would like to add your comma in the desired position, then convert it to float `float(st[:1] + '.' + st[1:])`